# How to remove the "Examples" combobox or change its text in Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I have a problem with Swagger UI where it displays an empty "Examples" combobox (marked yellow on the image below) which does not look good. Is there a way to remove it or change its text to something useful?

[image: Swagger 3.0 Petstore example]

I tried adding the `example` tag, but it won't work. The operation definition looks like this:

```yaml
post:
  tags:
  - pet
  summary: Add a new pet to the store
  operationId: addPet
  requestBody:
    description: Pet object that needs to be added to the store
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      application/xml:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
    required: true
  responses:
    405:
      description: Invalid input
      content: {}
  security:
  - petstore_auth:
    - write:pets
    - read:pets
```

Comment: Update: This bug was fixed in Swagger UI v. 3.23.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It was a bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5455) in Swagger UI v. 3.23.0-3.23.1 (and Swagger Editor 3.6.31) that was **fixed in v. 3.23.2**.